# Gauss Markov assumptions

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, sample

[image]

I think these two methods would differ, and the second method would be more accurate. But I am wondering that we know nothing about these parameters, maybe they could be the same, so from what angle should we approach this problem?

But I also think that the second method would be preferred under the Gauss Markov assumptions since "Distinct error terms are uncorrelated"is preferred. Thanks.

Comment: +1.  Think about how the precision of $\hat\beta$ increases as the spread of the $X_i$ increases.

Comment: Isn't the precision of the estimator decreases as the spread of the $X_i$ increases?

Comment: Is simple averaging optimal? Eg. consider [inverse variance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple intuition:

Imagine we're estimating the probability that a thumbtack lands heads.

Experiment 1 flips a thumbtack 5 times.
Experiment 2 flips a thumbtack 100 times.

Let's say from experiment 1, $\hat{b}_1 = .8$ and from experiment 2 $\hat{b}_2 = .6$ Which estimate is more precise? For an overall estimate based upon *both* experiments, should we calculate $\frac{1}{2} .8 + \frac{1}{2} .6$ (i.e. take the simple arithmetic mean) or is that in some sense sub-optimal? What weighting would correspond with a single experiment that flipped the thumbtack 105 times?

### Linear algebra based argument:

Let's split the sample in two.
$$ X = \left[ \begin{array}{c} X_1 \\ X_2 \end{array} \right]\quad \quad \mathbf{y} = \left[ \begin{array}{c} \mathbf{y}_1 \\ \mathbf{y}_2 \end{array} \right] $$

Now let's write the ordinary least squares (OLS) estimate $\hat{\mathbf{b}}$ for the full sample as a weighted sum of the OLS estimates for the subsamples.

$$ 
\begin{align*} \hat{\mathbf{b}} &= (X'X)^{-1}X'y \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{c} X_1'X_1 + X_2'X_2 \end{array}  \right]^{-1}\left[X_1'\mathbf{y}_1 + X_2'\mathbf{y}_2 \right]  \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{c} X_1'X_1 + X_2'X_2 \end{array}  \right]^{-1}\left[X_1'X_1(X_1'X_1)^{-1} X_1'\mathbf{y}_1 + X_2'X_2(X_2'X_2)^{-1} X_2'\mathbf{y}_2 \right] \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{c} X_1'X_1 + X_2'X_2 \end{array}  \right]^{-1}\left[X_1'X_1\hat{\mathbf{b}}_1 + X_2'X_2\hat{\mathbf{b}}_2 \right] \\
&= \left( \left[\begin{array}{c} X_1'X_1 + X_2'X_2 \end{array}  \right]^{-1}X_1'X_1\right) \hat{\mathbf{b}}_1 + \left( \left[\begin{array}{c} X_1'X_1 + X_2'X_2 \end{array} \right]^{-1} X_2'X_2\right)\hat{\mathbf{b}}_2 
\end{align*} $$

Now define $\hat{M}_{1} = \frac{X_1'X_1}{n_1}  \quad \hat{M}_{2} = \frac{X_2'X_2}{n_2} \quad \quad \hat{M} = \frac{X'X}{n} = \frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2} M_{1} + \frac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2} M_{2}$ where $n_1$ is size of subsample $X_1$ etc... And the idea is that $M = \mathrm{E}\left[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}' \right] $.
Then:

$$\hat{\mathbf{b}} = \left( \frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}\right)\left(\hat{M}^{-1}\hat{M}_1 \right) \hat{\mathbf{b}}_1 + \left( \frac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2}\right)\left(\hat{M}^{-1}\hat{M}_2 \right) \hat{\mathbf{b}}_2 $$

$\hat{\mathbf{b}}$ from OLS is in some sense a sophisticated weighted-average of the subsample estimates. How does this compare to the simple arithmetic average of $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_2$? Which way of combining  $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_2$ is optimal in a best linear unbiased estimator sense?

Note also that $\left( \frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}\right)\left(\hat{M}^{-1}\hat{M}_1 \right)$ is a matrix, not a scalar. And for $\hat{M} \approx \hat{M}_1$ you'll probably have something in some sense close to $\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$ as the weight on $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_1$.

Comment: I am not sure that I follow.. So what does this tell us?

Comment: So the whole result only depends on X in the end?

Comment: When you take the simple arithmetic average, you are doing $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_\mathrm{avg} = \frac{1}{2} \hat{\mathbf{b}}_1 +  \frac{1}{2} \hat{\mathbf{b}}_2$. When you do a regression on the full data, you are effectively combining $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{b}}_2$ using the formula in my answer. How are they different? What do we know is optimal in a BLUE (best linear unbiased estimator) sense? What's a simple thing that's not optimal with just using weights $\frac{1}{2}$ on $b_1$ and $b_2$?

Comment: @J.doe Do you know linear-algebra? If not, my answer/hints may be immensely confusing and you may be better off by ignoring the whole math argument.

Comment: Yeah I took linear algebra last semester, I'll take another look at the answer and hopefully I'll get it this time haha. Thank you for your patience!!

Comment: Does this imply that unless $n_1=n_2$, or else we should choose plan 2 instead?

Comment: @J.doe We know from the Gauss-Markov theorem that (ii) is optimal in the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE) sense! Hence (i) can't be better. What (ii) is basically doing is giving more weight to better estimates (possibly because $n_1 \neq n_2$ but possibly for other reasons as well). Equal weights is just immediately dubious if $n_1 \neq n_2$, but it does go beyond that.

Comment: Ah I think I got it. This problem is more difficult than I thought.. And I doubt if I'd ever come up with the answer if you didn't post the answers and hints. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, can I ask you another question? We are asked to model the demand for money as a function of interest rates and we are given two periods of data: one with interest rates were relatively stable and the other one were volatile. We can only choose one, but I don't know which one I should choose. What should I be taken into consideration? I am thinking that maybe I should choose the relatively stable one, because the regression line would be more accurate?

Comment: @J.doe Go read Whuber's comment and think about that. If you want to estimate what happens when someone turns a steering wheel, do you want a sample where the steering wheel barely is turned? Or where someone is turning the wheel a bunch?

Comment: I guess it is the second one, but how do we formalize the explanation of our choice?

Comment: @J.doe Whuber's comment expresses the underlying idea succinctly. You can also see it in the formulas, but I think I've given enough hints! (and have work to do.)